# JSR batch - constructor injection using @BatchProperty

Tags: java, spring-batch, batch-processing, jsr352

I am currently working on a JSR batch job. I tried injecting incoming parameters in my batchlet constructor.

```
@Inject
public MyBatchLet(@BatchProperty(name="prop1") String prop1){
    this.myProperty = prop1;
}
```

This throws a dependency exception.

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.batch.api.BatchProperty(name=)};
```

I am lost here, I will appreciate any help understanding this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch spec supports field injection only. So your code should be changed to inject the batch property to a field. For example,

```java
@Inject
@BatchProperty
private String prop1;
```

The batch property name defaults to the java class field name. Otherwise, you can specify the name with `@BatchProperty(name = "property-name")`.